# Resize open file dialog Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, fullscreen, dialog

I'm a little bit stuck here. I'm trying to get the common dialog that appears when you open/save a file in Internet Explorer fullscreen and be persistent. If i open the dialog, resize it, close it and open it again, it won't remember it's size and it resets to default.
I've tried digging around in the registry entries of the Common Dialog (Comdlg32), but haven't found any working solutions.

This problem only occurs in IE running on Windows 7. Other browsers and other versions of Windows don't seem to have this problem. Switching browser or OS is, sadly, no option in my scenario. Using third party application is also no option :(

Edit: The size settings of the common dialog windows that are opened are stored on a program by program basis in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\CIDSizeMRU.
Howerver, when i add a key for internet explorer (copied from a system where it does work) it just seems to ignore the entry.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. I'm not able to duplicate the problem you describe. My IE save dialog stays full screen, or any other size I set it, the next time I choose "Save as...". When you say you close it, how are you closing it?

Comment: Tried closing it by opening/ saving a file, click the close button, click the X or alt+f4.

Comment: I also tried doing all the above while holding ctrl or shift, because according to some info i found it is supposed to force remembering the size.

Comment: You may want to run `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt to ensure there isn't a system file corruption issue going on. Also, make sure you have installed all updates.

Comment: Didn't turn out to be a system file corruption after running sfc /scannow and all updates are installed :(

Comment: This was a problem when Windows 7 originally came out, but it was fixed. Maybe the PC you are dealing with does not have the updates you think it does, or something reverted. You may want to read this post to get some background and suggestions. [TechNet Article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5b524d53-df97-405d-835f-f081d106a19b/can-we-get-a-straight-answer-windows-does-not-remember-window-size-and-position-bug-or-by?forum=w7itproui)

Comment: This thread discusses the fact that windows only remembers the size of the last opened window, and not those previously opened. In my case it doesnt remember anything at all. Thanks for the effort anyway!